# Write in Topic in Kafka through Java Code

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

i am trying to write in Kafka Topic through JAVA, as i have created the Topic, but want to insert some data in that topic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with "I'm trying" ? Do you have any code which doesn't work ? Can you show it ? Otherwise there a lot of code examples online on how using a KafkaProducer, no need for a Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a synchronous producer. It should work with Kafka 0.11 (and a few prior releases too):

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.*;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongSerializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import java.util.Properties;

public class MyKafkaProducer {

    private final static String TOPIC = "my-example-topic";
    private final static String BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = "localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094";

    private static Producer<Long, String> createProducer() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "MyKafkaProducer");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongSerializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        return new KafkaProducer<>(props);
    }

    static void runProducer(final int sendMessageCount) throws Exception {
        final Producer<Long, String> producer = createProducer();

        try {
            for (long index = 1; index <= sendMessageCount; index++) {
                final ProducerRecord<Long, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(TOPIC, index, "Message " + index);
                RecordMetadata metadata = producer.send(record).get();
                System.out.printf("sent record(key=%s value='%s')" + " metadata(partition=%d, offset=%d)\n",
                    record.key(), record.value(), metadata.partition(), metadata.offset());
            }
        } finally {
            producer.flush();
            producer.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            runProducer(5);
        } else {
            runProducer(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
        }
    }
}
```

You may need to modify some of the hard-coded settings.

Reference: http://cloudurable.com/blog/kafka-tutorial-kafka-producer/index.html